# Trouble with multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, oop

I'm trying to come up with an abstraction for a game framework and one approach is to create,  for example, a graphics and audio class, these are the interfaces used by your games, and you derive specific implementations for your target platforms ( desktop/mobile/console ).

I have some example code of the idea here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Graphics
{
    virtual ~Graphics() {}
    virtual void Rect() {}
};

struct Text
{
    virtual ~Text() {}
    virtual void Print(string s) {}
};

struct IosGraphics : public Graphics
{
    void Rect() { cout << "[]"; }
};

struct IosText : public Text
{
    void Print(string s) { cout << s << endl; }
};

struct Output : public Graphics, public Text
{
};

struct IosOutput : public Output, public IosGraphics, public IosText
{
};

int main() 
{ 
    Output * output = new IosOutput();
    output->Rect(); // this calling Graphics::Rect not IosGraphics::Rect
    output->Print("Hello World!"); // this calling Text::Print not IosText::Print
    cin.get();
}
```

The problem is that output is using the Text::Print instead of IosText::Print, I wonder if this is related to the diamond problem and I might have to use virtual inheritance or something. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Make a draw of your class structure and you will see that it doesn't makes sense...somehow...

Comment: This is not an answer, and you shouldn't be doing it, and it won't work in a different situation... but: if you make `Text` and `Graphics` into virtual bases, you'll get the desired behaviour.

Comment: @picarus http://i.imgur.com/879yA.png ........


Ty you kerrek, it works and my compiler is giving me some cool messages, like ( one class is has dominance over the other! )

Comment: @AdamDreaver: Double diamond... but you really have to understand what's going on, because this is almost certainly not the right approach, and it's not going to be extensible. You can easily break this by adding overrides to `Output`, say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The diamond problem" isn't a problem, it's a symptom of not understanding the distinction between virtual and non-virtual inheritance. In the code above, the class `Output` has two base classes of type `Graphics`, one from `Output` and one from `IosGraphics`. It also has two base classes of type `Text`, one from `Output` and one from `IosText`. So `output->Print("Hello, World!)` calls the implementation of `Print()` in its base, that is, it calls `Text::Print()`. It doesn't know anything about `IosGraphics::Print()`.

If you change `IosGraphics` to have `Graphics` as a **virtual** base, and change `IosText` to have `Text` as a **virtual** base, and change `Output` to have `Graphics` and `Text` as **virtual** bases, then things will do what you want because of the **Dominance** rule. `Output` doesn't override `Rect()` but `IosGraphics` does, so virtual calls to `Output->Rect()` go to `IosGraphics::Rect()`, and similarly for `Text::Print()`.

I know, that sounds like magic. The rule is a bit weird, but it works. Try it.

Comment: You're a programming god! TYTY.

Answer (score 2):

In general, avoid multiple implementation inheritance at all costs. In your case, `IosOutput` has two copies of `Graphics` and `Text` in it, which is causing the problem.

The best solution is, however, not to use inheritance at all, but instead use membership -- `IosOutput` has members of type `IosGraphics` and `IosText`, and those may legitimately inherit from a more abstract `Graphics` and `Text`.

Also, consider interfaces -- classes with only pure virtual methods as an alternative solution.

Comment: I don't think your analysis of what's "causing the problem" is correct.